# Why C# Xunit Mock returning empty enumeration on IQueryable

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xunit

trying to mock one method in repository which having return IQueryable.
Please see the unit test method

```
[Fact]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        var mockZonal = new Mock<IBaseRepository<ZonalDefinition>>().SetupAllProperties();


        var list = new List<ZonalDefinition>() { new ZonalDefinition() { DestinationZone = "401" } }.AsQueryable();

        mockZonal.Setup(r => r.GetQueryableFromSql<ZonalDefinition>(new SqlQuerySpec(), new FeedOptions())).Returns(()=>list);

        _repoFactory.Setup(r => r.GetGenericRepository<ZonalDefinition>(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(mockZonal.Object);

        var afShipmentDetail = new AirFreightShipmentDetail();

        var response = _quoteRespository.SetCXShipmentTargetValue(afShipmentDetail);
        Assert.NotNull(response);
    }
```

while executing the test am getting the result for mocked method '*GetQueryableFromSql*' as '*Enumeration yielded no results'*

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RP8ui.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand Moq, you have to setup your method differently:

```
mockZonal.Setup(r => r.GetQueryableFromSql<ZonalDefinition>(It.IsAny<SqlQuerySpec>(),
                                                            It.IsAny<FeedOptions>()))
                      .Returns(()=>list);
```

The way you set it up, it would only match if those exact objects were passed to the method (which they won't).

If you need to be more specific with regards to the parameters to match, have a look at [the documentation](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#matching-arguments).